# Is there anyway to inject variable elements via chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Im building a chrome extension which injects CSS and JS to a particular website. I just wanted to know if there is any way to manipulate a variable element. As an example if I wanted to duplicate the user's username and place it somewhere else on the site. This is an example of such to the current DOM I have access to:

```html
<span class="nav-user">
  <li class="dropdown nav-item">
    <img alt="Avatar" class="nav-user-avatar" src="usersimage.png">
      <a aria-haspopup="true" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" aria-expanded="false">          <span class="nav-username">Rbxntl</span>
      </a>
        <div tabindex="-1" role="menu" aria-hidden="true" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        <span>Logout</span>
        </a>
     </div>
   </li>
</span>
```

To reiterate basically just to move this element somewhere else on the page that will allow it to work on all users when they have the extension installed, or possibly to duplicate and place the duplicate somewhere else. I have tried researching the problem but I cant seem to find the solution.

Comment: There's no such term as "variable element". I'm not sure what the trouble here is because duplicating a DOM element with its children is trivial - element.cloneNode(true) - but if the site wants its own event listeners attached on the element or its children as opposed to listeners on ancestors like `body` or `document`, cloning will produce an inert copy that doesn't have dynamic functionality of the original.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very experienced with the terminology of programming yet. By variable element, I just mean one that varies with each user as for example their username will be different so I can't just copy the html with jquery.

Comment: Sounds like basic string manipulation problem - use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Alright thanks, I will look into it.